# derive .configure of a php installation

Tags: php, installation, compilation

I have to upgrade from a specific version of PHP, which is managed, to a newer version that I need to compile myself. My issue is with the ./configure command which determines which packages and what is enabled or not etc. How can I derive the existing configuration from the outdated PHP so I can replicate it for the newer version of PHP that I will compile?  How can I derive this and what is enabled and disabled?

Comment: Some versions of PHP list it at the top of `phpinfo()`, have you checked there? Generally, however, most people just match their extensions and INI, the compilation is rarely that important

Comment: yeah, I did that but it has a lot of info and it is not clear what is configured through ./configure and what is the default. I'm using PHP 7.4 as the existing version and moving to 8.1